# Variable frequency sine generator

Tags: oscillator, frequency, vco

What is an simple option to generate a low freq. sine in range 10Hz to 200Hz? I tried to make a triangle and integrate it but I obtained a huge difference in amplitude as I change the triangle frequency.

I need to regulate frequency with constant amplitude.

Comment: If you insist on analog, take a look at this TI App Note: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa665c/snoa665c.pdf

Comment: How do you want to control the frequency? Pot?

Comment: @Mattman944 I’d like to control with voltage.

Comment: If you want to control with voltage, that rules out many in the app note that I referenced.

Comment: Note that while an integrated triangle wave *looks* like a sine wave, it's not quite a pure sine wave; it's a piecewise parabolic curve.

Comment: Thx @Hearth , I didn’t know that. How about integrating expontial curve?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický The only thing that integrates to give a sine wave is a cosine wave. You can use this to make an oscillator, actually, by setting up two integrators in a loop, using the fact that \$\frac{\partial^2 \sin x}{\partial x^2} = -\sin x\$.

Answer (score 2):

The modern way is to create the sine wave digitally and convert to analog with a Digital to Analog converter (DAC).

At the low frequency you desire that can be done in a cheap microcontroller followed by a DAC.

Alternatively you could use one of the many single-chip digital waveform generators available.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I was thinking similar way just to program sine table into eeprom and use the counter to increment memory address. Them use R2R to get analog output. I just try to ask if there is an “all analog solution”. It seems all needs a variable gain amp to manage constant amplitude.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický  - That's not easy. A common analog way is to create a constant amplitude triangle wave then shape it. This is done is devices such as the MAX038 and XR-2206.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "starting" solution.

You can use a VCO (square wave, triangle wave), input is analog V2 (output of a DAC 0->5 V).
Triangle wave is "constant" amplitude.
Follow with a ["triangle to sine"](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-sinediode.html) diodes converter.
Change the resistors by a 10th factor.

Change the frequency varying the capacitor (and V2).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm13700.pdf) for the LM13700 Dual Operational Transconductance Amplifier has a circuit for a voltage controlled sinusoidal oscillator which might meet your requirements. I've built this before and as far as I remember the output stays at a constant amplitude due to one of the stages being a limiter.

> The circuit of Figure 35 employs two LM13700 packages, with three of
> the amplifiers configured as lo-pass filters and the fourth as a
> limiter/inverter. The circuit oscillates at the frequency at which the
> loop phase-shift is 360° or 180° for the inverter and 60° per filter
> stage. This VCO operates from 5 Hz to 50 kHz with less than 1% THD.

[image: LM13700 Sinusoidal VCO]